# Difference in GHC versions - compile error

Tags: haskell, ghc, fibonacci

I was practicing my Haskell and I came across a weird problem which I was unable to find a solution to on the Internet. I decided to solve this problem:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fibonacci-fp

In as many ways I can think of. One way is to perform recursion with memoization where I want to use State monad as a cache. I have GHC 7.10.2 on my Windows 10 and GHC 7.6.2 on my Ubuntu 14.04. This code below compiles (and runs very well) on 7.6.2 and doesn't compile on 7.10.2 giving error wherever I type 'Map', for example:

> Not in scope: type constructor or class: 'Map.Map'
>
> Not in scope: 'Map.lookup'

```
module Main (
    main
) where

import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Control.Monad.State

type CacheState = Map.Map Int Int
type IOState a = StateT CacheState IO a

modNum :: Int
modNum = 100000007

fibsMod :: [Int]
fibsMod = 0 : 1 : zipWith (\x y -> (x + y) mod modNum ) fibsMod (tail fibsMod)

-- | calculate Fibs with memoization in map
memoizedFib :: Int -> IOState Int
memoizedFib n = do
    state <- get
    let x = Map.lookup n state
    case x of
        Just y ->
            return y
        Nothing -> do
            n1 <- memoizedFib (n - 1)
            n2 <- memoizedFib (n - 2)
            let n3 = mod (n1 + n2) modNum
            put (Map.insert n n3 state)
            return n3


query :: [Int] -> IOState ()
query [] = return ()
query (n:ns) = do
    fibNum <- memoizedFib n
    liftIO $ print fibNum
    query ns


main :: IO ()
main = do
    inputdata <- getContents
    let intList = (map (read :: String -> Int) . tail . words) inputdata

    evalIOState $ query intList
    where
        initState :: Int -> Map.Map Int Int
        initState upTo = Map.fromList $ zip [0 .. upTo] $ take upTo fibsMod
        --initState upTo = Map.fromList $ [(0, 0), (1, 1)]

        evalIOState :: IOState a -> IO a
        evalIOState m = evalStateT m (initState 10001)
```

Does anybody know why am I facing this problem? It's very disturbing.

**Additional question**
As you can see I didn't perform exactly recursion with memoization. However leaving one of those lines uncommented can change approach:

```
initState upTo = Map.fromList $ zip [0 .. upTo] $ take upTo fibsMod
--initState upTo = Map.fromList $ [(0, 0), (1, 1)]
```

The problem is that using the second line performs terrible. I don't know where I made a mistake, but I think it should run in linear time with memoization. However with this line my algorithm is clearly exponential (I couldn't even get the answer for 50-th Fib number - that long). What did I do wrong in this case?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to your comments I fixed my code. Obviously there was a problem with `mod` function (I completely don't know how did this compile on GHC 7.6.2). Also I changed:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
```

to:

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
```

and now this code below works as intended:

```
module Main (
    main
) where

import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Control.Monad.State

type CacheState = Map.Map Int Int
type IOState a = StateT CacheState IO a

modNum :: Int
modNum = 100000007

fibsMod :: [Int]
fibsMod = 0 : 1 : zipWith (\x y -> (x + y) `mod` modNum) fibsMod (tail fibsMod)

-- | calculate Fibs with memoization in map
memoizedFib :: Int -> IOState Int
memoizedFib n = do
    state <- get
    let x = Map.lookup n state
    case x of
        Just y ->
            return y
        Nothing -> do
            n1 <- memoizedFib (n - 1)
            n2 <- memoizedFib (n - 2)
            state <- get
            let n3 = mod (n1 + n2) modNum
            put (Map.insert n n3 state)
            return n3


query :: [Int] -> IOState ()
query [] = return ()
query (n:ns) = do
    fibNum <- memoizedFib n
    liftIO $ print fibNum
    query ns


main :: IO ()
main = do
    inputdata <- getContents
    let intList = (map (read :: String -> Int) . tail . words) inputdata

    evalIOState $ query intList
    where
        initState :: Int -> Map.Map Int Int
        --initState upTo = Map.fromList $ zip [0 .. upTo] $ take upTo fibsMod
        initState upTo = Map.fromList [(0, 0), (1, 1)]

        evalIOState :: IOState a -> IO a
        evalIOState m = evalStateT m (initState 10001)
```

So now the question comes down to: Why did I need to use Data.Map.Strict, how is it different and why GHC 7.6.2 didn't need it?

Comment: Problem not reproducible by copying and pasting into file. There is a different obvious error though, missing backticks around `mod`. Is this your real code?

Comment: For the problem you are reporting, my immediate guess is that you have a mistake in the `import` statement.

Comment: `put (Map.insert n n3 state)` uses the `state` from *before* you calculate `n1` and `n2`, so you are throwing away all the memoization from the recursions.

Comment: The code you showed should not be givign that error.  As @ReidBarton said, perhaps this isn't your real code?  My best guess is the code on your windows machine actually reads `import qualified Data.Map` and drops the `as Map` part.

Comment: Hello, everybody. Thank you very much for your comments! I fixed my code and edited question. Sorry for my mistake with `mod` function, I don't know how did this happen - the only error I was getting was with Map. Thank you so much @Ørjan Johansen, you are a genius! Wasn't able to localize this at all, now it runs very fast. So now the problem is only with imports and those are different in mentioned GHC versions.

Comment: Now that it works with `Data.Map.Strict`, change it "back" to `Data.Map` and I predict it will still work!

Comment: @ReidBarton, no it doesn't on GHC 7.10.2 - that's the point :-) All occurences of Map give 'Not in scope' error when I try to compile. Maybe it's not the compiler's version per se, but the version of containers package for example?

Comment: Did you specifically try changing your *working* code to use Data.Map? Because there's no plausible explanation for the behavior you report: it's far more likely that you are building the wrong version of your code. (Or else you broke your 7.10.2 installation in some very specific and unlikely way.)

Comment: @ReidBarton, yes I'm positive. To be more specific I'm using the latest version of HaskellPlatform with GHC 7.10.2 on my Windows 10. There must be something weird with installation then.